# Python - If statement, error local variable 'newfile' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysftp

I have following Python 2.7 script.

The script iterates through a CSV file that contains filenames, it then looks on an FTP server to try and find the filenames.

However, I get an error when the file isn't found on the ftp:

error local variable 'newfile' referenced before assignment

Ideally, I want the script to just move on to the next row in the file, if it can't find the previous file on the ftp. How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

```
def googleclouda(googlefile): 



    import time
    import pysftp 
    import sys
    import os
    from os import path
    from datetime import datetime
    import calendar
    import zipfile
    import re

    os.chdir("C:\Users\\xxx\python\\xxx\\")  

    oftp = pysftp.Connection(host="xxxxxx", username="xxxxxx", password="xxxxxx")
    d = datetime.utcnow()
    unixtime=calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())
    month = datetime.now().strftime("%m") 
    string = googlefile+month+".*\.txt$"  

    possibleFiles = oftp.listdir("/") 
    for filename in possibleFiles:
            filedate = re.search(string, filename)  
            if filedate:
                newfile = filename

    timestamp  = oftp.stat(newfile).st_atime 
    if timestamp  > unixtime - 604800:  
        newtime=unixtime + 3600 
        gaamfile='file_123_26807_' 
        zipname = gaamfile+str(newtime)+'.sync.zip' 
        create_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) 
        oftp.get(newfile, newfile)
        oftp.close()
        newfilename = gaamfile+str(newtime)+'.sync' 
        os.rename(newfile, newfilename)
        create_zip.write(newfilename)  
        create_zip.close()
        print newfile
    else: 
        print "No files found"


filecsv = 'filelist.csv' 

with open(filecsv, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('\n'): 
            googlefile = line.strip() 
            googleclouda(googlefile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this bit of code:

```
for filename in possibleFiles:
        filedate = re.search(string, filename)  
        if filedate:
            newfile = filename
```

`newfile` only gets defined `if filedate`. Either:

- Check your inputs so `if filedate` returns `True`.
- Place all subsequent code under the `if` clause (via extra indentation) so that it only get executed `if filedate == True`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you be able to share some example code of how I would implement your suggestions? Cheers

Comment: @NickEdwards. Unfortunately, I can't, as you haven't provided a reproducible example, or clarified what you want your output to be.

Comment: The script works until it reaches a file name in the CSV that is not on the FTP. The output is that the script just moves onto the next row in the csv and continues as is. I can't include the ftp credentials to replicate as there is sensitive data on there. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
            if filedate:
                newfile = filename
```

into this:

```
            if filedate and filename is not none:
                newfile = filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line:

```
timestamp  = oftp.stat(newfile).st_atime
```

If `newfile` is not assigned previously based on the if condition, you will reference it even if it's not assigned.

In the beginning of your script, as suggested by @cco, you can also set `newfile` to an empty string:
`newfile = ''`

You should structure so that the rest is only processed if `newfile` is assigned. You can add a condition on `newfile`.

---

Also, if I'm not mistaken, the following lines should be part of the for loop. Otherwise `newfile` will only contain the last filename found. It will be overwritten each time with the next one found.

```
timestamp  = oftp.stat(newfile).st_atime 
        if timestamp  > unixtime - 604800:  
            newtime=unixtime + 3600 
            gaamfile='file_123_26807_' 
            zipname = gaamfile+str(newtime)+'.sync.zip' 
            create_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) 
            oftp.get(newfile, newfile)
            oftp.close()
            newfilename = gaamfile+str(newtime)+'.sync' 
            os.rename(newfile, newfilename)
            create_zip.write(newfilename)  
            create_zip.close()
            print newfile
        else: 
            print "No files found"
```

Comment: This will still throw an error if `filedate` is not set. You need to set `newfile` to a falsy value (`0` or `None`, presumably) before the loop.

Comment: @KevinLemaire - Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. Would you be able to show me an example of how I should implement your suggestions?